# Enable stretch layout option to support bigger iPhones

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode7

Our current version of our iphone application in the app store simply stretches the layout to fill the iphone 6 and 6+. After the xcode 7 update, the app just runs as it would on an iphone 4 with black bars at the top. I understand that adding a launch storyboard resolves this. The problem then is that our layout is out of whack on the 6 and 6+.

Obviously fixing the layout to adapt to these screen sizes is what needs to be done, but we are in a pinch and just need to get a behind the scenes function update pushed out to our users ASAP. Is there anyway to go back to the old behavior where the UIView would just stretch to fill the screens?

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to the problem? The answer below is very hacky... It would be much better if there was an option to replicate xcode 6 behaviour in xcode 7

Answer (score 1):

This won't be an immediate fix, but it's a quick patch that might be worth trying.

If your view is always in portrait, this should work for you. If it requires rotating or a `UISplitViewController` on iPhone 6(s)+, then it might not.

Scale each subview in your view controller for the new screen size. Declare a couple macros for the device screen size:

```
#define kScreenWidth  [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width
#define kScreenHeight [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height
```

Then add a method to your view controllers that goes through all subviews to resize each view proportionately based on an iPhone 4 screen size.

```
- (void)resizeSubviews:(UIView *)view {
    CGRect frame = view.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.origin.x / 320.0f * kScreenWidth;
    frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y / 480.0f * kScreenHeight;
    frame.size.width = frame.size.width / 320.0f * kScreenWidth;
    frame.size.height = frame.size.height / 480.0f * kScreenHeight;
    view.frame = frame;

    for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
        [self resizeSubviews:subview];
    }
}
```

Then call that method after adding your subviews with:

```
[self resizeSubviews:self.view];
```

There are a lot of ways this could not work, but it covered me during the switch from iPhone 4s to iPhone 5.